# Vim Autoindent does not work

Tags: vimrc, vimscript, neovim

I'm configuring my Vim editor. Now I want it to automatically indent when I press enter after a parenthesis (like in modern IDEs)

```
function test() {

    |

}
```

I already have autoindent and smartindent enabled. I think I used a plugin in an old Vim config, but I can't remember which one it was. I hope you can help me, thanks

Comment: What is the file type of the file you are editing? ``:set filetype?``

Comment: Cross-posted here: https://www.reddit.com/r/vim/comments/vl2xb1/autoindent/

Comment: `'smartindent'` should do this, so it sounds like your setting may be overridden by something else in your config. What is the output of the command `:verbose set si? inde?`

Answer (score 1):

1. You're correct that `smartindent` and `autoindent` should do what you want, but it might be overruled by the archaic `compatible` setting.

Be sure you're not in vi compatible mode.   You want `set compatible?` to return `nocompatible`.   This means that Vim will not be backwards compatible to the old vi program.   In older Vim versions, it started up in `compatible` mode by default and left it to the users' .vimrc files to include `set nocompatible`.
Newer versions of Vim will automatically start up in `nocompatible` mode, which is what you want.

2. Many common file extensions will get the `filetype` setting assigned.   If `:filetype` returns `detection: ON` and `indent:ON`, then the filetype indentation might be setting the `indentexpr` to a function which should be better than `smartindent`, but maybe it's worse.   What is your filetype?
   If you're writing Javascript, then the filetype should be `javascript`.  If filetype detection and indentation is on, then the `indentexpr` should be `GetJavaScriptIndent()` which will do exactly what you want.
   I usually recommend not using `autoindent` and `smartindent` and instead use filetype indentation.

In summary, these two lines in a ~/.vimrc should help out:

```
set nocompatible
filetype plugin indent on
```

Comment: The quesion is tagged with "Neovim". So neither of these two apply.

Comment: Even if it is not applicable to neovim, this is good info to know.

Comment: PS a vimrc really needs `if &compatible | set nocompatible | endif`, or nothing at all, because vim now automatically sets nocompatible when a vimrc is processed.